# Git warning: Config remote shorthand cannot begin with '/'

Tags: git

I just upgraded Git from some old version, and now I get this warning message whenever I pull from a remote repository:

```
$ git pull
warning: Config remote shorthand cannot begin with '/': /mnt/titanium/repos.url
warning: Config remote shorthand cannot begin with '/': /mnt/titanium/repos.fetch
```

This remote repository is a directory on USB stick, which I use to transfer files to computers without direct network connection. USB stick is mounted at /mnt/titanium

```
$ git remote -v
warning: Config remote shorthand cannot begin with '/': /mnt/titanium/repos.url
warning: Config remote shorthand cannot begin with '/': /mnt/titanium/repos.fetch
origin  /mnt/titanium/repos (fetch)
origin  /mnt/titanium/repos (push)
```

My .git/config looks like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
[remote "/mnt/titanium/repos"]
        url = origin
        fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes//mnt/titanium/repos/*
[remote "origin"]
        url = /mnt/titanium/repos
        fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

I read about reasons for this change, but I don't understand what should I do to make this warning go away?

Comment: Could you include your `.git/config`, or at least the `[remote ...]` section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend editing your `.git/config` to rename the remote from `/mnt/titanium/repos` to simply `repos`. The url should still be `/mnt/titanium/repos`, but it shouldn't have that in the actual remote name. You may need to edit the `fetch` reference as well:

```
[remote "repos"]
    url = /mnt/titanium/repos
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/repos/*
```

**edit**

Now that I've seen your config, it looks like you simply have an extra remote named `"/mnt/titanium/repos"` in which the name and the URL of the remote are reversed, since it has a url of `origin` (not sure if from user error or software error). Anyhow, it looks like you don't need that at all, since the `"origin"` remote is defined correctly. You can delete the entire `"/mnt/titanium/repos"` remote (the line containing that string and following two lines), and shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Thanks. This computer used to have a network connection, so it pulled the changes from a server, and origin was set differently. At that time I added a USB stick as another option. Later, when network was removed, I googled and found some way to switch the origin (so that simple git pull/push without any arguments would work).

Comment: Now that I look at it, it seems that the command I googled then had "origin" and path in the wrong order. I probably tried, seen that it does not work, then reversed and it worked - but I didn't bother to edit config to remove the wrong line.